# How could we resolve IBMid in IBM Cloud Activity Tracker?

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, logdna

We use activity tracker to track activities on IBM Cloud.
how could we identify the user who initiated some action?

[image]

[image]

Comment: AT or AT with LogDNA?

Comment: AT without LogDNA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecated service [Activity Tracker has information about each field](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker?topic=cloud-activity-tracker-at_event#initiator). The `initiator.id` would map to the `userId` within your account.

You can see those IDs, e.g., on the command line like this:

```
ibmcloud account users --output json
```

It would produce a list with entries like:

```
   {
        "userId": "myemail@example.com",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "state": "ACTIVE",
        "ibmUniqueId": "IBMid-5555013NNN",
        ...
   }
```

BTW: For the new [Activity Tracker with LogDNA the event fields are similar](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Activity-Tracker-with-LogDNA?topic=logdnaat-event).

Comment: is there a different answer for the "w/ LogDNA" scenario? That might be useful to post here too.

Comment: do you have information how long we can use the (old) activity tracker?